# How to assign color scale to a variable in a 3D scatter plot?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, 3d, gradient

I'm a beginner in R and needs a bit of help for my scripting.
I managed to generate scale color gradient using library(ggplot2) on my 2D plots as follows;

```
z <- c(data$conf)
d <- qplot(x, y, xlab="Dimension 1", ylab="Dimension 2", colour=z)
d
d + scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(0, 1), data=data$conf, low="blue", high="red"))
```

I'm now trying to reproduce this gradient on a 3D plot, I used scatterplot3d or plot3d. I believe the colorRampPalette create a color gradient based on 327 rows (1…327) while I'm interested in  a gradient that is function of values in data$conf. I need a connection, but where?

```
attach(data)
t1 <- c(data$conf)
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))
e <- plot3d(x, y, z, col=jet.colors(327))
```

If you can help me that will be great – Or if you know any 3D plot/scale gradient package that can do a better job, cool too.

Comment: can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413678/how-to-assign-color-scale-to-a-variable-in-a-3d-scatter-plot?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are on the right track with `colorRampPalette()`, but really need something more like `colorRamp()`, which ['returns a function that maps values between 0 and 1'](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/colorRamp.html).

Even better would be a function -- call it `myColorRamp()` -- which is like `colorRamp()` but instead: (a) maps values between `min(values)` and `max(values)`; and (b) returns the colors as 7-character sRGB strings (e.g. "#F60008"), a format that `plot3d()` understands.

```
library(rgl)

myColorRamp <- function(colors, values) {
    v <- (values - min(values))/diff(range(values))
    x <- colorRamp(colors)(v)
    rgb(x[,1], x[,2], x[,3], maxColorValue = 255)
}

x <- sin((1:100)/10)
y <- cos((1:100)/10)
z <- seq(-20, 20, length.out=100)

cols <- myColorRamp(c("red", "blue"), z) 
plot3d(x = x, y = y, z = z, col = cols)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Josh. The results are 3D sammon projection of ~700 compounds with their respective probability to cross the blood-brain barrier.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's always (OK, often) interesting to know what an answer is actually being used for.